# Pymongo extract documents, modify the documents and update with replaceone method

Tags: python, mongodb

How can I update the existing document by using python without using update mongodb query???

```
aa = mongodb.findByCollection(resultCollectionName, {})
totalCount = (aa.count())
count = 0
for document in aa:
    values = document["RESULTPERMONTH"].values()
    document["RESULT_SUM"] = sum(values)
    document["RESULT_AVG"] = roundTwoDigits(document["RESULT_SUM"] / len(document["RESULTPERMONTH"])) if len(document["RESULTPERMONTH"]) != 0 else -1000
    document["RESULT_LEN"] = len(document["RESULTPERMONTH"]) 
    document["RESULT_MIN"] = min(values) if len(values) != 0 else -1000
    if "buyInfo" in document:
        del document["buyInfo"]
    if "sellInfo" in document:
        del document["sellInfo"]
    try:
        mongodb.database.get_collection(resultCollectionName).save(document)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    count = count +1
    if count % 10000 == 0:
        print(count / totalCount)
```

This is my previous code to update. Since save method is deprecated, I would like to replace that. But I don't want to use mongodb query but do want to use python processing.

How can I use replaceone in this case?

Comment: Your are trying to update one existing doc in mongo collection, and again inserting same document with same ObjectId, This is what the error desc means here. Why not directly update using update()

Comment: `mongodb._getCollection("RESULT").save(i)`

Comment: @Valijon Thank you so much, I was looking for your answer!

Comment: `save()` is deprecated. Use `replace_one()` instead.

Comment: @BellyBuster , can you check the question again? I changed my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [db.collection.replace_one()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/):

```
db.collection.replace_one({'_id': aa['_id']}, document, upsert=True)
```